# mongodb findOneAndUpdate only if a certain condition is met

Tags: mongodb

Following is my mongo db entries.

```
my-mongo-set:PRIMARY> db.stat_collection.find({name : /s/})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aabf231a167b3808302b138"), "name" : "shankarmr", "email" : "abc@xyz", "rating" : 9901 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aabf23da167b3808302b139"), "name" : "shankar", "email" : "abc1@xyz1", "rating" : 10011 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aabf2b5a167b3808302b13a"), "name" : "shankar1", "email" : "abc2@xyz2", "rating" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aabf2c2a167b3808302b13b"), "name" : "shankar2", "email" : "abc3@xyz3", "rating" : 100 }
```

Now i want to find an entry based on name but update a field only if a certain condition holds good.

I tried the following statement, but it gives me error at the second reference to $rating.

```
db.stat_collection.findOneAndUpdate({name: "shankar"}, {$set : {rating : {$cond : [ {$lt : [ "$rating", 100]}, 100, $rating]}}, $setOnInsert: fullObject}, {upsert : true} )
```

So in my case, it shouldnot update rating for the 2nd document as the rating is not less than 100. But for the third document, rating should be updated to 100.

How do i get it work?

Comment: Try `db.stat_collections.findOneAndUpdate(
  { name: "Shankar", rating: { $lt: 100 } }, {$set : { rating: 100 }, $setOnInsert: fullObject}, {upsert : true}
);`

Comment: in this case, if there is no entry with rating less than 100 and name equals shankar, a new document gets added since i have upsert=true. I want it to happen only if there is no doc with name shankar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/max/) is the operator you're looking for, try:

```
db.stat_collection.findOneAndUpdate( { name: "shankar1"}, { $max: { rating: 100 } }, { returnNewDocument: true } )
```

You'll either get old value (if is greater than `100`) or modify a document and set `100`

According to the documentation:

> The $max operator updates the value of the field to a specified value if the specified value is greater than the current value of the field. The $max operator can compare values of different types, using the BSON comparison order.

Comment: Thanks @mickl, $max suited my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should put all conditions in the query part of the update:

```
db.stat_collections.findOneAndUpdate(
  { name: "Shankar", rating: { $lt: 100 } },
  $set : { rating: 100 },
);
```

"If the name is Shankar and rating is less than 100, then set the rating to 100." is the above.

Comment: The idea is good however he won't get any results if the condition is not met.

Comment: @mickl I think that is what Op wants. Update when the condition is met.